# How to open multiple links from a single hyperlink from anchor tag string in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, anchor

I have a string that has multiple anchor tags passed to the frontend in ReactJs. This string is given by the service call.

```
eg: "<a href=\"https://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> National ID </a><a href=\"https://www.yahoo.com\" target=\"_blank\"> National ID </a>"
```

I want to display National ID once and open both the links on a blank page. I figured it out that by getting the `href` links, I can create an `onclick` function that opens both the links.

I wanted to know, how to extract `href` from the string. Or is there a better way to solve the issue that I have? Thanks in advance for any suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to parse string and extract links, like this one:

```
const input = '<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"> National ID </a><a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"> National ID </a>';
const regex = /href="(\S*)"/g;
const links = Array.from(input.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

So if you have high volume of anchor tags, then you can extract all the href values and add the href values in the array.

Code given below

```js
 

let hrefValues=document.getElementsByTagName('a')

let hrefArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i<hrefValues.length; i++)

{  

    hrefArray.push(hrefValues[i].href);

}

 

console.log(hrefArray);
```

```html
 


 

<a href="https://www.google.com/1" target="_blank">

<a href="https://www.google.com/2" target="_blank">

<a href="https://www.google.com/3" target="_blank">

<a href="https://www.google.com/4" target="_blank">

<a href="https://www.google.com/5" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Hey, the volume of these strings are very high and they are returned by the service call. It is not possible to add id to all the tags.

Comment: I had updated the code , please review